# Why the object[bar] has the same output as object[foo]?

Tags: javascript

In its page on property accessors, MDN has this:
Below link give a description regarding to javascript's Property_accessors, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

> ```
> var foo = {unique_prop: 1}, bar = {unique_prop: 2}, object = {};
> object[foo] = 'value';
> console.log(object[bar]);
> ```
>
> This also outputs "value", since both `foo` and `bar` are converted to the same string. In the SpiderMonkey JavaScript engine, this string would be `"['object Object']"`.

However, I cannot understand the explanation about the reason object[bar] equals to "value"... Could you please give a better explanation?

Comment: If objects as property names are boring, use functions instead ; ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your quote starts too early, this part:

> This outputs "value", since 1 is type-casted into '1'.

relates to the code *above* it, not the code below it.

To your question:

JavaScript property names are always strings or Symbols. So that code shows `"value"` because when you use an *object* as a property name, the object is implicitly converted to string as though you had used `String(obj)` on them, and plain objects coerce to the string `"[object Object]"` regardless of their contents. So it's the same property name regardless of whether you use `foo` or `bar`.

So this:

```js
var foo = {unique_prop: 1};
var bar = {unique_prop: 2};
var object = {};
object[foo] = 'value';
console.log(object[bar]);
```

is the same as this:

```js
var foo = {unique_prop: 1};
var bar = {unique_prop: 2};
var object = {};
object[String(foo)] = 'value';
console.log(object[String(bar)]);
```

and both `String(foo)` and `String(bar)` result in the same string, `"[object Object]"`:

```js
var foo = {unique_prop: 1};
var bar = {unique_prop: 2};
console.log("String(foo) =", String(foo));
console.log("String(bar) =", String(bar));
```

If you want to use objects as keys, you'll need to use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead. Example:

```js
var foo = {unique_prop: 1};
var bar = {unique_prop: 2};
var map = new Map;
map.set(foo, 'value');
console.log(map.get(bar)); // undefined
console.log(map.get(foo)); // "value"
```

If you can't use a map, use some unique property of the object.

---

Because someone is inevitably going to suggest it to you: You *could* use `JSON.stringify` to create a string for the object instead, but it's a bad idea. For one thing, if there's more than one property, it's brittle, because the property order in the JSON will depend on both the names of the properties and the order in which you add them. Example of why you shouldn't do with `JSON.stringify`:

```js
// Don't do this
var foo = {unique_prop: 1, another_prop: 2};
var object = {};
object[JSON.stringify(foo)] = "value";
console.log(object[JSON.stringify(foo)]); // "value" - so far so good
var bar = {another_prop: 2, unique_prop: 1};
console.log("foo.unique_prop = " + foo.unique_prop);
console.log("bar.unique_prop = " + bar.unique_prop);
console.log("foo.another_prop = " + foo.another_prop);
console.log("bar.another_prop = " + bar.another_prop);
// Seemingly the same object, so this should work, right?
console.log(object[JSON.stringify(bar)]); // undefined
// It doesn't because:
console.log("JSON.stringify(foo) = ", JSON.stringify(foo));
console.log("JSON.stringify(bar) = ", JSON.stringify(bar));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

As of ES2015, own properties in objects have an order, and `JSON.stringify` is required to follow that order when creating the string. So best not to do it via `JSON.stringify`.